# Why does my model not predict any probabilities larger than 0.5?

Tags: r, regression

I have created the following confusion matrix, which gives the output below.

```
Prob <- predict(modeltest, type=c("response"),working)
prob
confusion <- table(prob>0.5, working$buy)
confusion
     
          0    1
  FALSE 4522  436**
```

I can't work out why there are no true values.  If I change the code to the following, I get the subsequent matrix.

```
confusion <- table(prob>0.2, working$Phish)
confusion

         0    1
 FALSE 4499  427
 TRUE    23    9
```

I can understand that this is for a poor model but why can't I see True for the 0.5 version?

Comment: There's guarantee that your model will produce scores larger than any $0 < c$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here.  It's very confusing.  My confusion matrix output only has one line.  0  3456  234.  where is FN and TN line.  Is this a good thing or a bad thing.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the values of `Prob`? What's the largest value?

Comment: The largest is around 0.22. Beyond this point, the matrix goes to one line. how can I describe this relationship with reference to the matrix.  Am I saying that 22% of the time we get the following sensitivity and specificity working it out from the matrix?  Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between `prob` and `Prob`? What is the difference between `$buy` and `$Phish` ?

Comment: Are you training on an unbalanced data set? What kind of model is `modeltest`?

Comment: I'm saying that there's only 1 row because your data has 0 values of `Prob` that are larger than 0.5. We know this because the largest value of `Prob` is 0.22 < 0.5.